# "SCM error" when using dvc.api.get_url() to access S3 remote repository

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dvc

I have a remote repository that I want to use with DVC. I want to access my files through DVC in Python using the dvc.api module. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import dvc.api

path = 'data/test.csv'
repo = 's3://xxx/DVC_test/'
version = 'v1'

data_url = dvc.api.get_url(path=path, repo=repo, rev=version)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Cloning |                                                          |0.00/? [00:00,      ?obj   
                                                                                               
Cloning |                                                          |0.00/? [00:00,             
                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>                                                          
    data_url = dvc.api.get_url(path=path, repo=repo, rev=version)                              
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/
api/data.py", line 21, in get_url                                                              
    with Repo.open(repo, rev=rev, subrepos=True, uninitialized=True) as _repo:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)                                                                      
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/
external_repo.py", line 45, in external_repo                                                   
    path = _cached_clone(url, rev, for_write=for_write)
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/
external_repo.py", line 173, in _cached_clone
    clone_path, shallow = _clone_default_branch(url, rev, for_write=for_write)
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/func
y/decorators.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return deco(call, *dargs, **dkwargs)
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/func
y/flow.py", line 274, in wrap_with
    return call()                              
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/func
y/decorators.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/
external_repo.py", line 241, in _clone_default_branch
    git = clone(url, clone_path)
  File "/home/asokolov/Documents/BG/DVC_pipeline/dvc_test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/
scm.py", line 165, in clone
    raise CloneError("SCM error") from exc
dvc.scm.CloneError: SCM error
```

At the same time, running `dvc pull` works without errors.

Here's my `dvc.doctor`:

```
dvc doctor
DVC version: 2.47.0 (pip)
-------------------------
Platform: Python 3.9.16 on Linux-5.19.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.36
Subprojects:
        dvc_data = 0.42.1
        dvc_objects = 0.21.1
        dvc_render = 0.2.0
        dvc_task = 0.2.0
        scmrepo = 0.1.15
Supports:
        http (aiohttp = 3.8.4, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        https (aiohttp = 3.8.4, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        s3 (s3fs = 2023.3.0, boto3 = 1.24.59)
Cache types: hardlink, symlink
Cache directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Caches: local
Remotes: s3
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Repo: dvc, git
```

And my `.dvc/config.loval`:

```
['remote "dvc-remote"']
    url = s3://xxx/DVC_test/
    access_key_id = xxx
    secret_access_key = xxx
    region = xxx
```

Could you please suggest a solution to resolve the issue?

Comment: The error message "SCM error" indicates that there was an error while cloning the remote repository. This could be caused by various reasons such as incorrect permissions, network issues, or a problem with the remote repository.

Comment: Make sure your AWS access key and secret access key have sufficient permissions on the S3 bucket: Make sure that your AWS access key and secret access key have access to the S3 bucket. If you wish to verify the permissions, you can access the IAM console and review the policies associated with the access key.

Comment: Do I need special permissions for DVC even though I have CLI access to this bucket and am able to successfully use `dvc push` / `dvc pull`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are slightly misusing the python API see here: https://dvc.org/doc/api-reference/get_url

It looks like you would want something like this:

```py
import dvc.api

path = "data/test.csv"
remote_name = "dvc-remote"
repo = "https://github.com/username/repo.git"
version = "v1"

url = dvc.api.get_url(
    path=path,
    remote=remote_name,
    repo=repo,
    rev=version
)

print(url)
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I made a mistake with the parameters `dvc.api.get_url`! Thank you so much!